# Problem with initialize static std::vector<class> in same class constructor

Tags: class, visual-c++, vector, crash, initialization

How to correct declare static vector in class?
Currently I have crash on one line because vector initialize too late.

**Sample one**:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>    
class A{
private:
    int aValue;
public:
    static std::vector<A*> listOfA;

    A(int i)
    {
        aValue = i;
        A::listOfA.push_back(this); // !!! HERE crash in release mode only, in debug mode items add to vector, but remove when vector initialize
    }
};

A testA(1);
std::vector<A*> A::listOfA;



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

**Sample two**:

*classA.h*

```
#include <vector>

class A{
private:
    int aValue;
public:
    static std::vector<A*> listOfA;

    A(int i);
};
```

*classA.cpp*

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "classA.h"

std::vector<A*> A::listOfA;

A::A(int i)
{
  aValue = i;
  A::listOfA.push_back(this); // !!! HERE crash in release mode only, in debug mode items add to vector, but remove when vector initialize
}
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "classA.h"

A testA(1);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

In sample 2 if cpp files in project have this order(compilation order) all works fine:
classA.cpp
main.cpp

If order this, we have crash:
main.cpp
classA.cpp

Comment: I recommend to read more on "static initialization order fiasco"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quoted from: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14
There are many solutions to this problem, but a very simple and completely portable solution is to replace the global object listOfA, with a global function, listOfA(), that returns the object by reference.

```
std::vector<A*>& listOfA()
{
    static std::vector<A*> ans;
    return ans;
}
```

Since static local objects are constructed the first time control flows over their declaration (only), the above new listOfA() statement will only happen once: the first time listOfA() is called. Every subsequent call will return the same object. Then all you do is change your usages of listOfA to listOfA():

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // do stuff
    A::listOfA().dostuff();
    // do stuff
}
```

This is called the Construct On First Use Idiom because it does just that: the global Fred object is constructed on its first use.

The downside of this approach is that the object is never destructed. There is another technique that answers this concern, but it needs to be used with care since it creates the possibility of another (equally nasty) problem.

[Edit] Sorry nbt, didn't see that you already linked to the faq. He deserves the credit[/Edit]

Comment: You can create (on stack instead of heap) local static object in the global function <listOfA> and return it. The destruction concern will be handled by standard static object destruction. It's called lazy-initialization :P

Comment: Looking back at it, yes. I over thought the problem and answered a different issue.  What I posted is used to guarantee static initialization order for multiple static variables, when a normal static variable would have worked fine.  Editing my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Statics are initialised in the order they appear in a file, so when you say:

```
A testA(1);
std::vector<A*> A::listOfA;
```

the first static is initialised, but its constructor tries to use the second static, with undefined results.

If the statics are in different files, the order of initialisation is unspecified, so it may appear to work if you are lucky Or unlucky). In general, don't write code that depends on the order of initialisation of statics.

Comment: How to modify class for good initialization in  different files?

Comment: Don't modify it, simply don't do it. But your first sample would work if you swapped the initialisation order.

Comment: In real code it it different files, one file use class, another file with class